# Install topojson on the command line

Tags: topojson

I want to use `topojson` on the command line to simplify some files. npm will install topojson without any errors:

```
npm install -g topojson
```

But then running:

```
topojson
```

produces `-bash: topojson: command not found`. [This article](https://medium.com/@aendrew/creating-topojson-using-d3-v4-10838d1a9538) suggests that:

> topojson/topojson is no longer the command-line tools for manipulating
>   TopoJSON — that’s all been put in the topojson/topojson-client
>   repository.

So I am trying:

```
npm install -g topojson-client
```

But then trying `topojson-client` produces `command not found`, and so does `topojson` and I can't see any documentation in either repo explaining what to do. Can anyone suggest any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running stuff as a superuser you won't get executables put into standard system path locations. I seem to have a topojson installed and the executables are in the `.npm` folder for the package:

```
s ~/.npm/topojson/1.6.19/package/bin/
bower  package  topojson  topojson-geojson  topojson-group  topojson-merge  topojson-svg
```

These don't actually work for me probably because some other dependency is missing...

```
$ ~/.npm/topojson/1.6.19/package/bin/topojson-geojson 
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'rw'
```

but your installer should have put them somewhere...

### EDIT

assuming they still exist. My topojson as above is positively ancient. The command you want might be `geo2topo` now: https://github.com/topojson/topojson-server/blob/master/bin/geo2topo